# override a val in trait from Future

Tags: scala

I want to override the `val t` from  `getValue`  which returns a `Future`

```
trait demo{
  val t :String
}

class Test1 extends demo{

  override val t = "abc"
}

class Test2 extends demo{

  override val t = ""

  private def getValue ={
    Future(Option("abc"))
  }
```

}

Comment: You'd have to `Await.result(getValue)`, which kind of defeats the purpose of a `Future`, and then `getOrElse()` to unwrap the `Option`.

Comment: @jwvh can we use for comphrension for the same

Comment: you will have to wait for the Future to get complete otherwise i don't think we can do this

Comment: No. A `for` comprehension (which is just alternative syntax for `map()` and `flatMap()`) will look inside the `Future`, but it's still a `Future` (not a `String`) after the `for` completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you *can* do that kind of comes close to that is to `map` a future to an anonymous class extending `demo`:

```
val aDemo: Future[demo] = Future("abc").map { value => 
  new demo {
    override val t = value
  }
}
```

Of course, you can do that inside a for-comprehension as well, e.g.:

```
for (value <- Future("abc")) yield
  new demo {
    override val t = value
  }
```